# Polycom cURL to HTTP request

Tags: android, http, curl

I am using a [polycom](http://community.polycom.com/) device to make calls. I need to call a number from an android device. The polycom tutorial suggests that I use cURL for this purpose. However, since android does not support cURL, I would like to know is there anyway to make the request using HTTP?

This is the cURL command I am using-

```
curl --digest -u abc:xyz -d 
"<PolycomIPPhone><URL priority="Critical">SoftKey:Cancel </URL>
</PolycomIPPhone>" --header "Content-Type: application/x-com-polycom-spipx"     
http://1.2.3.4/push
```

where, abc:xyz is my username/password

I am unable to understand what the HTTP headers would be in this case.

**EDIT:** My polycom phone model is VVX-550

**EDIT 2:** Got it working using the code below:

```
 public void makeCall(){

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://1.2.3.4/push");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-com-polycom-spipx");


    if(isAuthRequested){
        DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("algorithm", "MD5");
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "PUSH Authentication");
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", nonce);
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("qop", "0");
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("nc", "0");
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("cnonce", DigestScheme.createCnonce());

        Header auth;
        try {
            auth = digestAuth.authenticate(new
                    UsernamePasswordCredentials("Username", "password"), post);
            post.addHeader(auth);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    HttpEntity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = new ByteArrayEntity(mXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if(!isAuthRequested){
                Header[] authResp = response.getHeaders("WWW-Authenticate");
                for(Header he : authResp){
                    Log.d("Log","Header: "+he);

                    String[] firstSplit = he.toString().split(",");
                    String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[1].split("=");
                    nonce = secondSplit[1];
                    nonce = nonce.replaceAll("\"", "");
                    Log.d("Log","Nonce:"+nonce);
                    isAuthRequested = true;
                    makeCall();
                }
            }
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("Log", "String result: "+result);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have some else platform that you can use cUrl, you can send a request to a echo server and see what contents you sent and convert them to Http.

Comment: Right. Thats what I thought as well. But wanted to avoid that. Will let you know how it turns out. Thanks for your help!